google console internal tests errors "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference ”
All Pixel devices were tested, and only the Pixel 8 log showed this error:
java.lang.NullPointerException:  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException:  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull (Parcel.java:3189)
at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:3167)
at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:3150)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:202)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:154)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call (ContentProviderNative.java:764)
at android.content.ContentResolver.call (ContentResolver.java:2466)
at android.content.ContentResolver.call (ContentResolver.java:2446)
at ekfr.a (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):29)
at  com.google.android.gms.wallet.intentoperation.setupwizard.PaymentsSetupWizardAccountChangeIntentOperation.onHandleIntent (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):252)
At com. Google. Android. Chimera. IntentOperation. OnHandleIntent (: com. Google. Android. The GMS @ 242013038 @24.20.13 (190400-633713831) : 2)
at ajdw.onHandleIntent (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):8)
at pbh.run (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):70)
at pbg.run (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):152)
at elbx.run (:com.google.android.gms@242013038@24.20.13 (190400-633713831):21)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)

I tried to use p8 pro, p8a and p8 in firebase test lab for testing, but only p8 printed such a content. I hope it would not print such an error log, so that every time I conduct internal testing, I would get an error asking me to make changes, or how should I make changes?

Having the same issue

I am experiencing the same issue in my application.

same issue, and my app has no in-app purchases.

We got the same issue - It seems like it is somehow related to app review time. Our app is currently 8 days In-review. This is the first time it happens. Any clue on how to fix it?

Please download the log file of the Pixel 8. Especially, look if the first "PRE_ON_CREATE" of "LifecycleMonitor" is way after the reported crash. This would be a clear sign that it is not your app that causes the crash

Is your app a payed app?

Maybe this two links can be useful for someone
https://forum.unity.com/threads/crash-with-nullpointerexception-occurring-on-all-unity-lts-versions.1606281/
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/3306

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Try to adding to your Gradle file:
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:19.4.0'
}

and to your AndroidManifest.xml:
<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
    android:value="true" />

More info here:
https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/setup

Anyone can confirm this works?

Ok I tried and it didn't work at all
